# Prevent insertion of duplicate documents into Lotus notes database

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus

I have a c# web api hosted in iis which has a post method that takes a list of document ids to insert into a lotus notes database.
The post method can be called multiple times and I want to prevent insertion of duplicate documents.

This is the code(in a static class) that is called from the post:

```
lock (thisLock)
{
   var id = "some unique id";
   doc = vw.GetDocumentByKey(id, false);
   if (doc == null)
   {
      NotesDocument docNew = db.CreateDocument();
      //some more processing
      docNew.Save(true, false, false);
   }
}
```

Even with the lock in place, I am running into scenarios where duplicate documents are inserted. Is it because a request can be execute on a new process? What is the best way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is: getdocumentbykey depends on the view index being up to date. On a busy server there is no guarantee that this is true. You can TRY to call a vw.Update, but unfortunately this does not trigger an update of the view index, so it might be without any effect (it just updates the vw object to represent what has changed in the backend, if the backend did not update, then it does nothing).

You could use `db.Search('IdField ="' & id & '"', Nothing, 0)` instead, as the search does not rely on an index to be rebuilt. This will be slightly slower, but should be way more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to store the inserted ids in some singleton object or even simply static list. And lock on this list - whoever obtains the lock verifies that the ids it wants to insert are not present and then adds them to the list itself.

You need to keep them only for a short length of time, just so that 2 concurrent posts with the same content does not update plus normal view index gets updated. So rather store timestamp along id, so you can clean out older records if the list grows long.

Comment: Okay, I see. Can use something like a  MemoryCache as well?

Comment: pretty much - and that lets you avoid the task of removing old items :-)

Comment: Or a FIFO list of fixed length.